# Citing a blog in background information (not prior art)

Tags: uspto, citation, background

For a USPTO utility patent, in my background section I would like provide a reference to an interview (the interview included in a blog post available at archive.org).

This is not a prior art reference. Instead, this is just an evidence of the problem space that the patent is addressing.

The questions are:

a) Should this reference (to archive.org) be included in IDS?

b) Is a http link to archive.org enough, or should I take screen shots and attach the black & white image of those in IDS?

c) How do invoke the reference in my background section, for example:
" According to Andrea ELLIOT, 2/3rds of the respondent in her survey, indicated that lack of tools is the problem (see http://archive.org/http.alliot/blog) ..."
Or should there be another way to include the reference to the blog?

Comment: Why adding it to the IDS? If you want reference it in the specifications.

Comment: @Moti thx for the follow up. That was question (a). If IDS is not needed,  how does one reference, in the background section, an archive.org blog post  (that is the format of the reference)

Comment: Is there in it information that does not appear in another reference? You could call the USPTO to ask how to reference it - they help with applications.

Comment: I am not sure that your explanation need any references.

Comment: @Moti. Yes that information that I want to include in the Background section does *not*  appear in the references I am citing in IDS. In IDS I am citing patents and other prior art known to public. What I would like to reference in the Background is an article with a survey results, stipulating why my invention is needed. I will continue looking at other examples to see I can figure out, how they do references to archive.org

Comment: Call the USPTO - they are quite helpful.